# Exim4 crypteq with MySQL lookup always fails

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, email, exim

I got an Exim 4.80 server on Ubuntu 14.04. I want to switch from Dovecot Auth to MySQL. The passwords are stored as crypt (with sha256, beginning with $5$).
The expansion looks like this:

> server_condition = ${if crypteq{$3}{${lookup mysql{SELECT password FROM accounts LEFT JOIN domains ON accounts.domain=domains.id AND domains.domain='${quote_mysql:${domain:$2}}' WHERE accounts.name='${quote_mysql:${local_part:$2}}'}}}{yes}{no}}

When I turn on debug logging on, I get something like this:

> 10   subject=$5$fBzbQG0FRF1Lt2QI$Nhmrw5gKq62vmHDD8Eov9WCoGRPkk-----REDACTED----
>
> 10   crypted=$5$fBzbQG0FRF1Lt2QI$Nhmrw5gKq62vmHDD8Eov9WCoGRPkk-----REDACTED----

Both REDACTED are exactly equal. Then the following happens:

> 10 expanded string: no

I dug around in the Exim source code and found that the following code is responsible for the debug message and the result of crypteq

```
  #define STR(s) # s
  #define XSTR(s) STR(s)
  DEBUG(D_auth) debug_printf("crypteq: using %s()\n"
    "  subject=%s\n  crypted=%s\n",
    (which == 0)? XSTR(DEFAULT_CRYPT) : (which == 1)? "crypt" : "crypt16",
    coded, sub[1]);
  #undef STR
  #undef XSTR

  /* If the encrypted string contains fewer than two characters (for the
  salt), force failure. Otherwise we get false positives: with an empty
  string the yield of crypt() is an empty string! */

  tempcond = (Ustrlen(sub[1]) < 2)? FALSE :
    (Ustrcmp(coded, sub[1]) == 0);
  }
```

So subject= is the coded variable, which is generated by the crypt function, while crypted= is the sub[1]. These are both the same. The success of the operator is only dependant on weather sub[1] is longer than two characters (which apparently is true) and they are the same (which SHOULD also be true).

Does anybody know why this happens?

Edit: It doesn't happen if I put a hash directly in the brackets without MySQL lookup. There seems to be an expansion failure with MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so for anyone else stumbling upon this problem:
The MySQL expansion somehow adds whitespace (even though in the database are clearly none).
To solve the problem, encapsulate your MySQL expansion inside a substr with the length of your hashes. An example for sha256-crypt hashes would be:

> ${substr{0}{63}{${lookup mysql{

Then it should work.